# Shortening C++ If condition

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have a very long if statement that checks for winning conditions of a tic-tac-toe board:

```
if 
((tttPositions[i][j][0] && tttPositions[i][j][1] && tttPositions[i][j][2] == 1) 
|| (tttPositions[i][j][3] && tttPositions[i][j][4] && tttPositions[i][j][5] == 1) 
|| (tttPositions[i][j][6] && tttPositions[i][j][7] && tttPositions[i][j][8] == 1) 
|| (tttPositions[i][j][0] && tttPositions[i][j][3] && tttPositions[i][j][6] == 1) 
|| (tttPositions[i][j][1] && tttPositions[i][j][4] && tttPositions[i][j][7] == 1) 
|| (tttPositions[i][j][2] && tttPositions[i][j][5] && tttPositions[i][j][8] == 1) 
|| (tttPositions[i][j][0] && tttPositions[i][j][4] && tttPositions[i][j][8] == 1) 
|| (tttPositions[i][j][2] && tttPositions[i][j][4] && tttPositions[i][j][6] == 1))
{
    if (j = 0)
        cout << "x wins" << endl;
    if (j = 1)
        cout << "o wins" << endl;
}
```

This looks really ugly.. is there a way to keep track of the winning conditions separately to greatly reduce the length of this if statement?

I put the multiple tic tac toe boards into a 3D vector where each box is 2x9, the first row represents the 'x' positions and the second row represents the 'o' positions, so like:

```
110000011
001110000
```

represents:

```
x x o
o o _
_ x x
```

Comment: You can use loops for checking the conditions.

Comment: You could create functions to check for a winner vertically, horizontally and diagonally.

Comment: On a side note: `=` is assignment, while `==` checks equality, so `if (j = 0)` isn't quite right... but I guess it's just a typo as you've use `==` correct earlier in the code.

Comment: Trying to think about how to do loop checks for every vertical, horizontal, and diagonal combination seemed a lot more complicated than just checking against 8 predetermined winning combinations, but I was wondering if there was a way to put them in a set or something to check against.

Comment: Yes: put them in a set, then write a loop that checks against them.

Comment: I wasn't sure if a set was even a thing, I just used something like it in Matlab, how do I do this in C++?

Comment: `==1` are not necessary. You're also using them the wrong way.

Comment: In general, your syntax should be `if ((a == 1) &7 (b == 1)  && (c == 1))`.

Comment: You could start by creating a short named reference to `tttPositions[i][j]` and I also don't see the reason for all those `==1`s

Comment: Well, the easiest way to collect them would just be an array. But maybe I've misguessed what implementation you had in mind; maybe writing it in pseudocode would help.

Comment: Why not just use one [3][3] that is tristate, init to 0 x's are -1 o's are 1.. If any column or row adds to -3 or 3 there is a winner... (Checking diagonals is 2 other statements...)

Comment: As an aside; storing positions as a bitmask rather than as an array of 0-1 values might allow some simplifications.

Comment: trying to do something like: if (a || b || c || d, etc... ) where a = {1,2,3}, b = {4,5,6} kind of thing, but I'm not sure what the syntax is supposed to be

Comment: Is this a 3D game?  Normal 2d games only use 2d matrices.

Comment: it's multiple 2D games

Comment: So you are checking across games?  I don't understand the need for a 3rd array dimension.

Comment: @AustinMW: Make `a` an array of 3 values. Write a function whose job is to "check those three board positions". (or do the test inline, if you really want to)

Comment: it's kind of like a 3D board because it's 200ish 3x3 boards stacked

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions I think I've got a good direction to go in now

Comment: Another aside: it might help to simplify things if you wrote a function so that the code snippet would just be `if(is_winning_position(tttPositions[i][j])) { /* do something */ }`.

Comment: So you represent `o` and `_` in the same manner??? Something is fundamentally wrong in your representation method!

Comment: Your code is also broken - O will never win because when you check who has won, you assign to `j` instead of checking equality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a lambda that accepts 3 integers, and checks if they are set in the array. You can also bind `tttPositions[i][j]` to a reference just to make typing it a little less cumbersome.

```
auto& pos = tttPositions[i][j];
auto check = [&pos](int a, int b, int c) {
    return (pos[a] == 1) && (pos[b] == 1) && (pos[c] == 1);
};

// these three lines don't shorten the code, but
// they do make the if statememt more readable, imo
bool horizontal = check(0, 1, 2) || check(3, 4, 5) || check(6, 7, 8);
bool vertical = check(0, 3, 6) || check(1, 4, 7) || check(2, 5, 8);
bool diagonal = check(0, 4, 8) || check(2, 4, 6);
```

With this, your `if` becomes much simpler (and self documenting due to the variable names):

```
if (horizontal || vertical || diagonal)
```

A further simplification (again, not in code size, but in readability) would be to factor all this out into a function. I'm not sure what type `tttPositions[i][j]` is, but assuming it is an array of 9 ints, you could do this:

```
bool check_win_condition(int const (&pos)[9]) {
    // all the stuff I did before, except instead of an if statement, just return    
    return horizontal || vertical || diagonal;
}
```

Then in your other function, the `if` becomes simply this:

```
if (check_win_condition(tttPositions[i][j]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider creating a data structure at compile time to store the winning lines and then traverse that data structure at runtime to check if a player position includes a winning line instead of a lot of `if`s.

I noticed you have a lot of duplicate checks in your condition. For example you are checking `tttPositions[i][j][4]` four times. The cost is probably insignificant but it would be nice to reduce that.

One data structure you could use to store the winning lines would be a kind of tree. At the top of the tree would be a carefully chosen selection of positions that are included in all winning lines and for each of those parent positions as children you have the winning lines that include those positions.

The tree would only need to have two levels which I've unimaginatively called `Parent` and `Child` and stored in a flat arrays. The `Parent` stores the start and end index of it's children. The `Child` stores the two other positions in the winning line:

```
struct Parent {
  int pos;
  int children_start;
  int children_end;
};

using Child = std::pair<int, int>;

using Parents = std::array<Parent, 4>;
using Children = std::array<Child, 8>;

// Position indexes:
// 0 | 1 | 2 
// ----------
// 3 | 4 | 5
// ----------
// 6 | 7 | 8
//                                       centre            top-left  bottom-right
constexpr Parents parents =   {{         {4,0,4},          {0,4,6},    {8,6,8}   }};
//                                          |                 |           |
//                                 +-----+--+--+-----+     +--+--+     +--+--+
//                                 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
constexpr Children children = {{ {0,8},{2,6},{1,7},{3,5},{1,2},{3,6},{2,5},{7,6} }};
```

Add a couple of `begin` and `end` functions so we can do a range-based for loop on a `Parent`:

```
Children::const_iterator begin(const Parent& p) {
  return children.begin() + p.children_start;
}

Children::const_iterator end(const Parent& p) {
  return children.begin() + p.children_end;
}
```

And with that in place we are then able to write a function that checks if a position is a win with:

```
using PlayerPositions = std::array<int, 9>;

bool isWin(const PlayerPositions& pos) {
  for (auto& parent : parents) {
    if (pos[parent.pos]) {
      for (auto& child : parent) {
        if (pos[child.first] && pos[child.second])
          return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WDNOiQXIJYXWeBGt).

It's arguable whether this makes things much simpler in this case but it would be easier to generalise to more complicated game rules. You could even load your winning positions at runtime.